# OpenVPN connection breaks after a few seconds

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, ubuntu-12.04

For the last hours I have been trying to connect to a VPN network through openVPN.
My connection settings are:

IPv4 tab:

```
Method: Automatic VPN
Routes: Use this connection only for resources on its network.
```

Then on the VPN tab:

```
fw01.vcloud.kirkeweb.dk
Type: Password with Certificates(TLS)
```

Under ADVANCED:

```
In General tab:
  Use custom gateway port is checked
  Use a TCP connection is checked
In TLS Authentication:
  Use TLS Authentication is checked.
```

The log is:

```
Aug  7 14:41:42 aegir NetworkManager[1188]: <info> Starting VPN service 'openvpn'...
Aug  7 14:41:42 aegir NetworkManager[1188]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 27429
Aug  7 14:41:42 aegir NetworkManager[1188]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Aug  7 14:41:42 aegir NetworkManager[1188]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
Aug  7 14:41:42 aegir NetworkManager[1188]: <info> VPN connection 'fw01-TCP-8081-gc-config-v2' (Connect) reply received.
Aug  7 14:41:42 aegir nm-openvpn[27435]: OpenVPN 2.2.1 x86_64-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Mar 13 2014
Aug  7 14:41:43 aegir nm-openvpn[27435]: Control Channel Authentication: using '/home/lebowski/Desktop/KWvpn/fw01-TCP-8081-gc/fw01-TCP-8081-gc-tls.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
Aug  7 14:41:50 aegir NetworkManager[1188]: <info> VPN connection 'fw01-TCP-8081-gc-config-v2' (IP Config Get) reply received.
Aug  7 14:41:50 aegir NetworkManager[1188]: <info> VPN Gateway: 46.29.101.168
Aug  7 14:41:51 aegir NetworkManager[1188]: <info> VPN connection 'fw01-TCP-8081-gc-config-v2' (IP Config Get) complete.
Aug  7 14:41:51 aegir NetworkManager[1188]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: started (4)
Aug  7 14:42:10 aegir NetworkManager[1188]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 2
Aug  7 14:42:10 aegir NetworkManager[1188]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Aug  7 14:42:10 aegir NetworkManager[1188]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
Aug  7 14:42:10 aegir NetworkManager[1188]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Aug  7 14:42:10 aegir NetworkManager[1188]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Aug  7 14:42:17 aegir NetworkManager[1188]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' disappeared
```

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say without your server configuration, but you should first try and use the default client configuration options, namely to use UDP instead of TCP.

The default protocol/port combination for openVPN is UDP/1194, I would suggest you first attempt to use that instead of TCP/1194. If you're still not able to connect, check the server configuration, as well as the server logs, and update your question with the details.